# How can I label my axis after it print out all the data and mark for each data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The coding below is my code. I would like to label the axis after it print all the data and the mark for each data. I don't know why the label name only display at the begin.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

def init():
   global points
   points = np.loadtxt('Surface.txt')

def animate(i):
   ax1.clear()
   ax1.plot(points[:i, 0], points[:i, 1], points[:i, 2])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval = 1000)
ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('y')
ax1.set_zlabel('z')

plt.show()
```

The content of the Surface.txt is

```
0  0  3
1  1  4
2  4  8
4 16  6
5 25  5
6 36  3
```

Comment: set the labels in `def animate` i think

Comment: Sorry for my unclear description. Actually I would like to get my label name for the xyz axis after it print out all the data and also mark each of the data. Now, the label problem is solved. There still left 1 question for the marker. I would like to mark each of the data. Can you help me? Thank you so much and sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: I mean the data is coordinate since there have 3 data in 1 line. So, each line of the data represent 1 coordinate (ex:(5,9,2)). Then, I would like to mark each of the coordinate with a marker to clearly know the location of the data in the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish that by also adding the `set_label` commands inside the `def animate()` function like this

```
def animate(i):
   ax1.clear()
   ax1.plot(points[:i, 0], points[:i, 1], points[:i, 2])
   ax1.set_xlabel('x')
   ax1.set_ylabel('y')
   ax1.set_zlabel('z')
```

So the final program will look like shown below :

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

def init():
   global points
   points = np.loadtxt('Surface.txt')

def animate(i):
   ax1.clear()
   ax1.plot(points[:i, 0], points[:i, 1], points[:i, 2])
   ax1.set_xlabel('x')
   ax1.set_ylabel('y')
   ax1.set_zlabel('z')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval = 1000)
ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('y')
ax1.set_zlabel('z')

plt.show()
```

Comment: It's works, thanks. I have 1 more question for the data pointer. I'm going to mark each data. Can you help me? Thank you very much !!

Comment: @KohKhengHong what do you mean mark each data ?? Elaborate on that

Comment: I mean from my text file there, they got a lot of data and 3 column right? So it means that 1 row of data represent a coordinate. For example, 3 6 2 , x=3 , y=6, z=2 , so the 1 data is (3,6,2) represent 1 coordinate. Then, I would like to mark each of the coordinate with a marker. Therefore, I can know the location of the data from the graph.

Comment: Bro, I have been solved the problem. Thanks a lot!